# JAXB enumeration with numeric values

Tags: enums, xsd, jaxb

I want to restrict input values like this

```
<simpleType name="SomeCode">
  <restriction base="string">
    <enumeration value="036222B"/>
    <enumeration value="036111C"/>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

But this does not generate an Enum. I suspect it is because the values start with numbers and this is not allowed for Enum values.

Is there any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here is my answer to a similar question that may help (see issue 2):

- [Enums don't match schema: problem with jaxb or xsd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820113/enums-dont-match-schema-problem-with-jaxb-or-xsd/4830804#4830804)

There are a couple of enumeration values that are causing this issue.  These issues can be overcome through the use of a JAXB external binding file (see below).

**Enum Issue #1 - Empty String**

Some of your enum values are empty string (""), which is causing a String rather than an enum property to be generated:

```
<xs:enumeration value="">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Blank</xs:documentation> 
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
```

**Enum Issue #2 - Numeric String**

Some of the enum values are numbers which is causing a String rather than an enum property to be generated:

```
<xs:enumeration value="6">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>6th grade</xs:documentation> 
   </xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
```

**Bindings File (bindings.xml)**

The following bindings file can be used to address the issues with the *educationLevelType*, the concepts here can be applied to all the problematic types:

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://www.acf.hhs.gov/programs/cb/systems/nytd/nytd_data_file_format.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='educationLevelType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='6']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="SIX"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='educationLevelType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='7']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="SEVEN"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='educationLevelType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='8']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="EIGHT"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='educationLevelType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='9']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="NINE"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='educationLevelType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='10']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="TEN"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='educationLevelType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='11']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="ELEVEN"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='educationLevelType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='12']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="TWELVE"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='educationLevelType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="BLANK"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

The XJC call can be made as follows (the -nv flag is described below):

```
xjc -nv -b bindings.xml -d out http://www.acf.hhs.gov/programs/cb/systems/nytd/nytd_data_file_format.xsd
```

This will cause the following Enum to be generated:

```
package gov.hhs.acf.nytd;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnum;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnumValue;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name = "educationLevelType")
@XmlEnum
public enum EducationLevelType {

    @XmlEnumValue("under 6")
    UNDER_6("under 6"),

    @XmlEnumValue("6")
    SIX("6"),

    @XmlEnumValue("7")
    SEVEN("7"),

    @XmlEnumValue("8")
    EIGHT("8"),

    @XmlEnumValue("9")
    NINE("9"),

    @XmlEnumValue("10")
    TEN("10"),

    @XmlEnumValue("11")
    ELEVEN("11"),

    @XmlEnumValue("12")
    TWELVE("12"),

    @XmlEnumValue("post secondary")
    POST_SECONDARY("post secondary"),

    @XmlEnumValue("college")
    COLLEGE("college"),
    @XmlEnumValue("")

    BLANK("");
    private final String value;

    EducationLevelType(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static EducationLevelType fromValue(String v) {
        for (EducationLevelType c: EducationLevelType.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```

**maxOccurs Issue**

For the maxOccurs issue, the following command line with the *no verify* (-nv) flag can be used to parse the XML schema:

```
xjc -nv -d out http://www.acf.hhs.gov/programs/cb/systems/nytd/nytd_data_file_format.xsd
```

This will get you past the following error without having to modify the XML schema:

> parsing a schema... [ERROR] Current
>   configuration of the parser doesn't
>   allow a maxOccurs attribute value to
>   be set greater than the value 5,000.
>   line 41 of
>   http://www.acf.hhs.gov/programs/cb/systems/nytd/nytd_data_file_format.xsd
>
> Failed to parse a schema.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-enums.html

Comment: Do you have the XSD that you used in the example? The link http://www.acf.hhs.gov/programs/cb/systems/nytd/nytd_data_file_format.xsd is no longer available.

Comment: Thx for the blog, it helped me with the part where restriction is actually String.  But this is not working for `<xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger">`

Comment: Very old answer, so I don' t know if anybody is reading this, but... 

My usecase has a lot of values, each one a number followed by a text. These might change in the future by some other party. So I would be helped if I could influence the nameing strategy in some way (e.g. prefixing with a fixed value or changing the order of text and number). Is there anything that can be done in that department?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You could define the enum yourself instead of having XJC generate it. Then you could instruct XJC to use that enum. You'll need an adapter class, though.

```
import acme.MyEnum;

public class MyEnumadapter {

    public static MyEnum unmarshal(final String value) {
        if(value == null)
            return null;
        //use some method to identify the enum by the value and return
    }

    public static String marshal(final MyEnum value) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        //use some method to get the value for the enum
    }

}
```

Either in a bindings file or embedded in the schema, customize the bindings like this:

```
<bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='SomeCode']">
    <javaType name="acme.MyEnum"
        parseMethod="MyEnumAdapter.unmarshal"
        printMethod="MyEnumAdapter.marshal"/>
</bindings>
```

MyEnumAdapter is in the default package here, so make sure you use the fully qualified names when doing this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This code is more simpler way, works for me.

```
@XmlEnum(value = Integer.class)
public enum SomeEnum {
  @XmlEnumValue("0")
  Value1,
  @XmlEnumValue("1")
  Value2,
  @XmlEnumValue("2")
  Value3;
}
```