# jaxb doesn't generate enums with base integer

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb

I have following xsd:

```
<xs:simpleType name="resultcode">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:enumeration value="0" id="Approved_no_error">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="Approved_no_error"/>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
```

JAX-B just does nothing, no errors, no warnings just doesn't generate this class. If change base from `xs:integer` to `xs:string` then it's ok. But I need exactly integer values.

I generate classes with maven:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>AuthGateway</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
```

And question 2. JAX-B and IDE (IDEA) doesn't allow whitespaces in id attrribute. Why?

`<xs:enumeration value="0" id="Approved_no_error">` - ok
`<xs:enumeration value="0" id="Approved no error">` - not ok

Is it correct behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an external binding file to get the behaviour that you are looking for:

- [JAXB enumeration with numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175363/jaxb-enumeration-with-numeric-values/7175896#7175896)
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-enums.html

Comment: damn.
`code`(<xs:simpleType name="resultcode">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jxb:typesafeEnumClass/>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:enumeration value="0" id="Approved_no_error">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="Approved_no_error"/>`code`
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>)`code`

Comment: Good doc for the purpose: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Developing_Applications_Using_JAX-WS/files/JAXWSCustomTypeMappingEnum.html