# Converting xsd enum to java class in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, enums, jaxb, xsd

I have a problem with converting xsd schema to java class in Eclipse.
The following code gives me headache:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ErrorCode">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="200"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

This enum is not being generated beacuse of the `value="200"` piece of code. If I have something other than a number, for example string "hello" this will generate enum in java without a problem.
I tried using `xs:int` still have the same problem. Am I missing something? What is the problem with numbers if I use `xs:string`?

Tank you for help

Comment: JAXB has problems with enum values starting with a number. Check [this quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569299/jaxb-doesnt-generate-enums-with-base-integer). I think you'll find your answer there.