# JAXB generated enums when invoked through wsdl2java

Tags: enums, jaxb, wsdl2java, xjc

This is a follow-up question to [JAXB enumeration with numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175363/jaxb-enumeration-with-numeric-values/7175896#7175896). A more thorough explanation can be found at http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-enums.html, which links back to that posting. I will be using Blaise's blog posting as a starting point. It was very useful, thank you.

When I call xjc as shown on the blog and pass it the XSD file and the bindings file, the generated types are the same as shown on the blog, i.e. as required. Well and good.

But my Maven build does not invoke xjc directly on my set of XSD files; it invokes wsdl2java on my WSDL files, which include my XSD files. I can pass the -b parameter to xjc through the wsdl2java invocation (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html, example 7), and when I do that, the enum type is generated correctly according to the bindings file but the field that uses it --- Person.educationLevel in the example at  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-enums.html --- has type String, not EducationLevelType as it should.

I have also tried using an inline customization instead of an external binding file, i.e. decorated the education-level-type simpleType element in the XSD file with

```
    <annotation>
        <appinfo>
            <jxb:typesafeEnumClass>
                <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="1-6" name="ONE_TO_SIX"/>
                <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="6-12" name="SIX_TO_TWELVE"/>
                ...etc...
            </jxb:typesafeEnumClass>
        </appinfo>
    </annotation>
```

and this works nicely, even when used through wsdl2java: the enum is generated correctly, and the field has type EducationLevelType.

However, we do not own the XSD files so using an inline customization is not an option.

So, how do I make this work?

Any help is much appreciated.