# Maven CXF wsdl2java, underscore added in string enumeration before number

Tags: java, maven, cxf, wsdl2java

I got an issue with CXF. I got the following enumeration in my xsd, which is generated into java :

```
<xs:simpleType name="EnumCodeDetailActionFonctionnelle">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        [many more]
        <xs:enumeration value="RET_PIE"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="RET_PI4"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="RET_PI2"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="RET_PI1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="RES_COU"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="RES_AFF"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="REP_AFF"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="REN_REP"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="REL_PI2"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="REL_PI1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="RELANCE"/>
        [many more]
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But here is the generated code :

```
@XmlEnum
public enum EnumCodeDetailActionFonctionnelle {
    [many more]
    RET_PIE("RET_PIE"),
    @XmlEnumValue("RET_PI4")
    RET_PI_4("RET_PI4"),
    @XmlEnumValue("RET_PI2")
    RET_PI_2("RET_PI2"),
    @XmlEnumValue("RET_PI1")
    RET_PI_1("RET_PI1"),
    RES_COU("RES_COU"),
    RES_AFF("RES_AFF"),
    REP_AFF("REP_AFF"),
    REN_REP("REN_REP"),
    @XmlEnumValue("REL_PI2")
    REL_PI_2("REL_PI2"),
    @XmlEnumValue("REL_PI1")
    REL_PI_1("REL_PI1"),
    RELANCE("RELANCE"),
    [many more]
}
```

Why is there an underscore before each number on the code, eg: RET_PI**_**4("RET_PI4")?
And is there a way to get rid of it?

Thx ;)

Comment: is it related to JAXB spec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely related to JAXB : http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/weird-enum-names-tt5715788.html#a5716086

Solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7175896/1478667