# No enum in generated code using JAXB

Tags: enums, jaxb, code-generation

My enum class

```java
@XmlType
@XmlEnum(Integer.class)
public enum  Error {

 @XmlEnumValue("1")
    ENUM_VALUE_1(1, "some string 1", "some string 1"),
 @XmlEnumValue("2")
    ENUM_VALUE_2(2, "some string 2", "some string 2");

  private Error(int errorCode, String msgKey, String message) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
    this.msgKey = msgKey;
    this.message = message;
 }
}
```

Generated xsd

```xml
<xs:simpleType name="error">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
     <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

binding I am using

```xml
 <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
     <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='error']">
         <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass ref="packageName.Error" />
     </jaxb:bindings>
 </jaxb:bindings>
```

The problem is there is no enum file is getting generated. I am using "maven-jaxb2-plugin" for code generation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enums don't match schema: problem with jaxb or xsd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820113/enums-dont-match-schema-problem-with-jaxb-or-xsd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation will not create a Java enum for XML enumerations that start with numeric values.  You can use an external binding file to cause an enum to be generated.

```xml
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='error']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='1']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="ONE"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='error']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='2']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="TWO"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**Full Example**

- [Enums don't match schema: problem with jaxb or xsd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820113/enums-dont-match-schema-problem-with-jaxb-or-xsd/4830804#4830804)

---

**UPDATE**

> Then what is the point of adding following annotation -
>   @XmlEnumValue("1")

In your start from Java classes use case you used the `@XmlEnumValue("1")` annotation to map your enum to the desired XML structure.

```xml
  <xs:simpleType name="error">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

JAXB implementations don't generate JAXB information into the XML schema, so if someone wants to generate a Java model from the generated schema then a binding file can be used.

Comment: Then what is the point of adding following annotation - @XmlEnumValue("1")

Comment: @WhiteRoses - Your use case is you want to generate a JAXB model from that schema fragment correct?

Comment: When reading this it all sounds logical that an enum should not start with a numeric value. However I didn't get any clear error when running JAXB via Maven. I added the `<verbose>true</verbose>` option to my `<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>` `<execution/>` section in my `pom.xml` file and then I saw an exception being thrown when running the compile goal in Maven. This might be helpful for others to enable **verbose** mode.